# Deadlock when using condition variables for two way communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, deadlock

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?
I want foo and bar to be printed alternatively.
Sometimes it hangs in the first iteration, and in some cases goes on for a while before stopping.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
void foo()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
        cv.wait(ul);
        std::cout<<"bar"<<std::endl;
        ul.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t(foo);
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;
        cv.notify_one();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
        cv.wait(ul);  
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the actual communication! You have a mutex, but it doesn't protect anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition variables only signal a change, they aren't very useful by themselves. You need to combine it with a state.

Add another variable which dictates whose turn it is.

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
int turn = 0;

void foo()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
        if( turn == 1 ) {
            // my turn
            std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;

            // tell them it's their turn
            turn = 0;
            cv.notify_one();
        } else {
            // not our turn, wait for a change.
            cv.wait(ul);  
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(foo);
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
        if( turn == 0 ) {
            // my turn
            std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;

            // tell them it's their turn
            turn = 1;
            cv.notify_one();
        } else {
            // not our turn, wait for a change.
            cv.wait(ul);  
        }
    }
}
```

The mutex is used for safe access to the `turn` variable, and whenever it's changed, you notify the condition variable so other threads can wake up and check the new value.

---

EDIT: Assuming you understand the above, to solve your puzzle:

```
void foo()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        cv.notify_one();
        cv.wait(ul);  
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
    std::thread t(foo);
    while(true)
    { 
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; 
        cv.notify_one();
        cv.wait(ul);
    }
}
```

In other words, you just need to lock the mutex from outside of the loop, before you start the sub-thread, so it's clear to the logic whose turn is first. Then you do the action, signal the condition, and then wait for the other thread to signal back.

Flow of logic:

```
Main Thread             Sub Thread
------------------------------------------
Lock Mutex

Create Subthread

                        Try to lock mutex 
                        but it is busy.

Print "foo"             ...waiting for mutex...

Notify cvar             ignores notification,
                        (still waiting for mutex)

Wait on cvar            Obtains lock
                        (when waiting on a cvar, the lock is released.)

...waiting...           Prints "bar"

Notified, but the       Notify cvar
mutex is still locked           
so we are waiting.

Obtains lock again      Wait on cvar

Print "foo"             ...waiting...

(etc...)
```

Comment: Just locking the mutex at main, like your second example works fine. Why should I have the additional turn flag ?

Comment: It's just more useful in a practical scenario, while the second example works, it's not flexible at all

Comment: Unless you have the other thread waiting for the notification the whole time it doesn't work. In other words, it's not multithreaded.

Comment: In this case, I am trying to implement a version of python generators in C++. It seems to work asynchronously without the flag. Will probably need to add flags in future to signal the return of the 'producer' function.

Answer (score 0):

Well. `main` calls `notify`, then `foo` calls `notify`, then `main` locks the mutex and waits, then `foo` blocks at the mutex. Deadlock.